# I can't answer a protected question even I have enough rep

Tags: bug

I can't find an option to answer any question which is protected. As it says that at least 10 rep is required but I already have 51 rep. Why is it so? Example:

[image: bug]

**Question: [How can I keep my cat off my keyboard?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/9531/how-can-i-keep-my-cat-off-my-keyboard)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reputation required to answer a protected question ignores the +100 account association bonus that comes with having an account on another site with enough reputation. Instead, you must earn 10 reputation on this site through questions and answers. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question) for more info on protected questions.

Answer (score 3):

Anyone who joins a site with association bonus rep needs to have **110 rep** to answer protected question.

Since you put a 50-rep bounty, reducing your rep to 51, you need to earn **59 rep** (not 10) to pass the requirement to answer protected question.

This might be a bug, as reported on MSE: [Stack Exchange doesn't allow me to answer protected questions because I gave away earned rep in bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231498/241919)

Comment: I am confused from your answer. Why not 60? (As 1 rep earned for joining account, and 9 required for answering protected, you are saying that 8 more rep is required. Why not 9?  )

Comment: Because the threshold is set to 110, not 111. It has been tested and proven (the detail is on the answer of the linked MSE question)